# How to utilize PromiseKit to ensure a queried object has been retrieved before proceeding?

Tags: swift, xcode, parse-server, promisekit

I am programming an app which utilizes a parse-server (hosted by heroku) database. I have several functions which pull information from the DB, but they are all inherently asynchronous (because of the way parse's `.findObjectinBackground` works.) The issue with this as that the later DB queries require information from previous queries. Since the information being pulled is asynchronous, I decided to implement PromiseKit to ensure that the object has been found from `findObjectinBackground` from the first query, before running the second query.
The general form of the queries is as follows:

```
let query = PFQuery(classname: "Hello")
query?.findObjectsInBackground(block: { (objects, error) in
       if let objectss = objects{
           for object in objectss{ //object needs to be pulled
               arrayOfInterest.append(object)
               //array must be appended before moving on to next query

            }
        }            
})
```

I just do not know how exactly to do this. This is the way I would like to implement it:

```
import PromiseKit
override func viewDidLoad(){
    when(/*query object is retrieved/array is appended*/).then{
        //perform the next query
    }
}
```

I simply don't know exactly what to put in the `when()` and the `.then{}`. I tried making the queries into their own individual functions and calling them inside those two (when and then) functions, but I basically get told that I cannot because they return void. Also, I cannot simply ensure the first query is *run* in the `when()` as the `query.findObjectinBackground`(in the query) being asynchronous is the issue. The object specifically needs to be *pulled*, not just the query run, before the next one can fire.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Do you want create your promise?](http://promisekit.org/docs/making-promises/)

You need write a function that return a `Promise<Any>`. In your case, need to encapsulate the entire code inside of `Promise { fulfill, reject in HERE}`. For example:

```
func foo(className: String) -> Promise<[TypeOfArrayOfInterest]> {
    return Promise { fulfill, reject in

        let query = PFQuery(classname: className)
        query?.findObjectsInBackground(block: { (objects, error) in
            if let error = error {
                reject(error) // call reject when some error happened
                return
            }

            if let objectss = objects {
                for object in objectss{
                    arrayOfInterest.append(object)
                }

                fulfill(arrayOfInterest) // call fulfill with some value
            }
        })

    }
}
```

Then, you call this function in `firstly`:

```
firstly {
    foo(className: "Hello")
}.then { myArrayOfInterest -> Void in
    // do thing with myArrayOfInterest
}.catch { error in
    // some error happened, and the reject was called!
}
```

Also, I wrote a post in my blog about, among other things, PromiseKit and architecture. It may be helpful:  http://macalogs.com.br/ios/rails/ifce/2017/01/01/experiencias-eventbee.html

**Edit**

More complete example:

```
func foo() -> Promise<Int> {
    ...
}

func bar(someText: String) -> Promise<String> {
    ...
}

func baz() -> Promise<Void> {
    ...
}

func runPromises() {
    firstly {
        foo()
    }.then { value -> Promise<Any> in
        if value == 0 {
            return bar(someText: "no")
        } else {
            return bar(someText: "yes")
        }
    }.then { _ /* I don't want a String! */ -> Promise<Void> in
        baz()
    }.catch { error in
       // some error happened, and the reject was called!
    }
}
```

Or if you don't want a `catch`:

```
_ = firstly {
    foo()
}.then { _ in
    // do some thing
}
```

Swift have a greate type inference, but, when use PromiseKit, I recommend always write a type in `then` closure, to avoid erros.

Comment: I understand your answer, but do I need to use the result of `foo()` in the `.then` statement? I just want to make sure `foo()` runs (and appends the array), and then with the `.then` I'd just like to run another query. Is that doable?

Comment: just to illustrate what I meant by the previous comment, what I eseentially want is:
`firstly { 
      foo()
}.then { _ in
      otherQuery()
}.then { _ in
      thirdQuery()
}. catch {error in
      print(error)
}`

Comment: @AlekPiasecki Yes, you can to make it, but, maybe do you need write explicitly a return type, in this case, `then { _ -> Promise<Any> in ... }`. I edited my answer, to exemplify .